# How to test $state.go in Karma

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, state, karma-jasmine

I know there are a few `$state.go` unit test questions on here already, but none seem to work for me. I have simple controller logic which chooses a state.

```
if (true) {
    $state.go('home.default');
} else {
    $state.go('home.new');
}
```

In order to test which state is hit i've tried the following:

```
it('should return a state', function () {
    spyOn($state, 'go');
    $state.go('home.default');
    expect($state.go).toHaveBeenCalledWith('home.default');
});
```

this always works because of the line `$state.go('home.default');` which basically makes the test redundant, because i'm just calling which state i want then testing it. I want to see which state the controller calls.

I'd expect the test to be something like this:

```
it('should return a state', function () {
    spyOn($state, 'go');
    expect($state.go).toHaveBeenCalledWith('home.default');
});
```

But this doesn't work because it isn't called even though i know in the controller it is, any suggestions?

Comment: Controller should be instantiated between 'spyOn' and 'expect', and it isn't.

Comment: @estus I inject the controller in a beforeEach at the top, how do i then instantiate inbetween the spy?

Comment: Nobody prevents you from doing  'spyOn' in beforeEach. It doesn't matter if it is in 'beforeEach' or 'it', but spy should be set up before spied function will be called.

Comment: thank you, i think that's solved it. The spy needed to be in my beforeEach before the controller

Comment: Don't forget about and.callThrough(), otherwise the spy may break other tests.

Answer (score 2):

1. In your test folder create new file with `stateMock` module. Copy code  from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/alexanderjeurissen/1c45ca694ad333baeddd).
2. In test:

   ```
   beforeEach(module('stateMock'));

   beforeEach(inject(function ($state) {
       state = $state;
       state.expectTransitionTo('home.default');
   }));

   it('should return a state', function () {
       // something happen and return true and you expect that
       // $state.go('home.default') should work
       expect(state.current.name).toBe('home.default');

       // if it does not happen, expect return false and state.expectTransitionTo return error
   });
   ```